# Calculate the position in xaml grid/canvas by knowing which(in order of declaration) child element it is

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

Say I want each button in a canvas to be +25px lower than the first.

I'd need to get

```
y-coordinate = "starting y" + ( 25px * self.which nth child element am I)
```

Is this the best/right approach when I don't want to use stack panels and the like?

To clarify: What I'm trying to achieve is for buttons within a certain element to all dynamically calculate where they should be relatively based on the first elements position plus which nth element they themselves are against the first.

**How do I do this in xaml?**

**Clarification: Knowing how to actually get the y coord or position of the previous sibling is pretty key to what I'm asking.**

Answer (score 0):

use IMultiValueConverter.

```
<Canvas Name="parent">
        <Button Name="first" Width="10" Height="10" 
                Canvas.Top="30"/>
        <Button Width="10" Height="10">
            <Canvas.Top>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CanvasConverter}" ConverterParameter="top">
                    <Binding ElementName="parent"></Binding>
                    <Binding ElementName="first"></Binding>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Canvas.Top>
        </Button>
        <Button Width="10" Height="10">
            <Canvas.Top>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CanvasConverter}" ConverterParameter="top">
                    <Binding ElementName="parent"></Binding>
                    <Binding ElementName="first"></Binding>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Canvas.Top>
        </Button>
</Canvas>
```

with:

```
public class CanvasConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Canvas can = values[0] as Canvas;
        Button btn = values[1] as Button;
        Button btn0 = values[2] as Button;
        if (parameter.Equals("top"))
            return Canvas.GetTop(btn) + can.Children.IndexOf(btn0) * 25;
        else if (parameter.Equals("left"))
            return Canvas.GetLeft(btn) + 0;
        return null;
    } 

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
}
```

Don't forget the resource part:

```
 <local:CanvasConverter x:Key="CanvasConverter" />
```

Comment: You're manually setting margin for each button tho, even with the binding? I'm trying to make coords/position dynamic

Comment: Can you use a IValueConverter?

Comment: Yes, the framework version isn't an issue if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Knowing how to actually get the y coord or position of the previous sibling is pretty key to what I'm asking.

The `Canvas` panel has a `Children` collection of its child `UIElements`. You can get the position of a specific element in this collection using the `IndexOf` method.

Getting and setting the coordinates of such an element is then simply a matter of calling the `Canvas.Get*` and `Canvas.Set*` methods.

The following sample code should give you the idea:

```
Button button = new Button { Content = "..." };
canvas.Children.Add(button);

int buttonIndex = canvas.Children.IndexOf(button);
int previousElementIndex = buttonIndex - 1;
if(previousElementIndex > -1)
{
    //get the coordinates of the previous element
    UIElement previousElement = canvas.Children[previousElementIndex];
    double x = Canvas.GetLeft(previousElement);
    double y = Canvas.GetTop(previousElement);

    //set the coordinates of the button
    Canvas.SetTop(button, y + 25);
    Canvas.SetLeft(button, x + 25);
}
```

> How do I do this in xaml?

XAML is a *markup* language. You implement your logic in a *programming* language such as C#.